# User can't edit user profile picture

Tags: users

Drupal 7

Users can't edit their own profile pictures. The admin can edit them, but the regular user cannot edit his own. A user can see their own picture, but if they click the Edit tab it is not listed as a field that can be edited.

In /admin/config/people/accounts/fields I can see "picture", but there are no links to edit.

In /admin/config/people/accounts pictures can be enabled, but I see no relevant settings.

On /admin/people/permissions I see no relevant permissions.

Is there something obvious we are missing to enable users to edit their own profile pictures?

Edit: Screenshots below (with some data blanked out)

**Viewing profile (the ghost guy image is the actual profile pic, just sample data):**

[image: User viewing profile]

**Editing profile (no user picture field here):**
[image: User editing profile]

Comment: Can you provide steps to reproduce? On my local I can edit the picture.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/RliPW.png

Comment: Also I performed this on fresh drupal installation.

Comment: Hi Vishal. As a regular, non-admin user you are able to edit your profile picture?  That is, of course, what I would expect by default. The problem is that I don't know what is causing *this particular site* to be different. As I mentioned, there seems to be no way to edit the "picture" field, and there seem to be no relevant permissions or options where I mentioned looking. So trying to find out what we are missing here.

Comment: please upload screenshot of the form.

Comment: @GregHolmes could you try a default theme? Just to rule that out.

Comment: @Neograph734, it _does_ show up in a default theme (Bartik)!